# After Deploying on Azure NextJs App wrapped in Express, app loads forever

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, next.js

Hi I am trying to deploy nextjs app using devOps project with server.js which looks like that:

```js
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
    
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
    
app.prepare()
.then(() => {
  var port = process.env.port || 3001
  const server = express()
    
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })
    
  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:433')
  })
})
.catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

For devOPs project I set up github, vsts and then it goes off to azure.

I used the default set up for nodejs, only what I did additionaly in VSTS pipelines I added npm script "npm run build".

My agent job in buld looks like this:

- -User node version
- -Npm install application dependencies
- -Npm custom (Added by me, run build)
- -Archive Files
- -Public Artifact drop.

And in release:

- Azure Deployment: Create Azure App
- Deploy Azure App Service

The problem is that Build succedes same as release, but then when I try to access the website it loads forever. I did my research but found nothing.

I have been trying to make it work for 3 days now... Please help

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I've tried the exact same steps with, also with a Next.js app, and get a 404 when trying to reach the site. According to Azure the server is running though.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I successfully deployed NextJs App to Azure App service by using Azure Devops build and release pipelines.

Below are three issues I faced. I am also sharing solution screenshots for each issue.

1. Azure App service Node version should be compatible with your nextjs.

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpkuY.jpg
2. Missing web.config file at root

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vSvR.jpg
3. Incorrect port number in server.js and incorrect script tags in package.json

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvBeZ.jpg

My build pipeline looks similar like you. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMQA7.png